# Why does graph $y=(\ln y/\ln x) x-\ln y/\ln x (x^2/y)+x$ not include $x = y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Why does the graph $y=(\ln y/\ln x)x (-\ln y/\ln x (x^2/y))+x$ not include all positive $y$ and $x$ for which $y = x$? When I plotted this graph on desmos , the plot did not include the line $y = x$, even though the equation is solved for all $y = x$. This equation came up in the context of me trying to prove that the equations of the solutions to $x^y = y^x$ intersect at the point $(e,e)$

Comment: Not clear. Does $y=(\ln y/\ln x)x -\ln y/\ln x (x^2/y)+x$ stands for:
$$y=\frac{\ln y}{\ln x}x -\frac{\ln y}{\ln x (x^2/y)+x}?$$ Or does it stands for:
$$y=\frac{\ln y}{\ln x}x -\frac{\ln y}{\ln x} (x^2/y)+x?$$ 
Other interpretations are feasible!!!! 
Please, **clarify** this point, your equation is really ambiguous.

Comment: It stands  for the second one. Have edited the question to show this

Comment: What makes you believe the graph given by desmos is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we substitute $y=x$ in the equation
$$y=-\frac{x^2 \ln y}{y \ln x}+\frac{\ln y}{\ln x}x+x$$
we get $x=-x+x+x\to 0=0$ undefined.

Thus the equation above is not equivalent to $$x^y=y^x\tag{1}$$

I strongly recommend to simply prove by direct inspection that $x=y$ is a set of solution of $(1)$, and use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342821/self-intersection-of-the-implicit-curve-xy-yx-0) to prove that $(e,e)$ is a self intersection.

Hope this helps

Comment: I believe you misread my question. The equation was: y=-lnx/lny (x^2/y)+(lnx/lny)x+x. I think you missed the "x" in the second term of the equation

Comment: @Zzyzx To a greater extent your equation is not equivalent to the exponential one

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.

Comment: @Zzyzx I had the same curiosity about $x^y=y^x$, a few years ago :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2342821/self-intersection-of-the-implicit-curve-xy-yx-0